# How to redirect toward a specific node from front-page in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, nodes, redirection, i18n-l10n

I have a multi language site made in Drupal 7. And I want to check if I am on the front page then if true to redirect the user to a to some specific node.

I have tried different methods:

1. to create a page `front--page.tpl.php` and then to check language and then redirect
2. I have put this code in `page.tpl.php`:

   ```
    global $language;

    if ($node->nid == 1) {
        if ($language->language == "en") {
            header('Location: en/home');
        } elseif ($language->language == "fr") {
            header('Location: fr/accueil');
        }
    }
   ```
3. I am using i18n module for Drupal 7 so I have tried also to use `$conf['i18n_variables']` in `settings.php` like that:

   ```
     $conf['i18n_variables'] = array(
        'site_frontpage',
        'site_name',
     );
   ```

But I have not succeed to do it. Have you any suggestions ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

page--front.tpl.php simply allows you to create a different page template than the default page.tpl.php template. When drupal loads the homepage and there is a page--front.tpl.php it will laod that template instead.

If you want to check if you are on the homepage you can use the is_front variable. It would be best to use hook_boot in a custom module.

```
hook_boot(&$vars) {
  if($vars['is_front']) {
    // do your redirect
  }
}
```

You can use [drupal_goto()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_goto) to handle the redirect.

Comment: I have did a mistake, I have used `front--page.tpl.php` instead of `page--front.tpl.php`. So I have tried as you said (using `page--front.tpl.php`), however it was too complicated so I have abandon it.

Comment: Finally is working. I am using your idea to put in `template.php` the preprocess hook.

Comment: The `hook_preprocess_page` is an early process ? In the perspective to not consume much time till loading. In practice is working fast, I will test it on a remote server.

Comment: You should use hook_boot. hook_preprocess_page are a very late process.

Comment: note that your default front-page in admin/config/system/site-information can't be set to the same page or else you'll get an infinite redirect loop

Comment: There is no `$vars` in hook_boot(): https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_boot/7.x

Answer (score 4):

Using a custom module that implements a menu handler for "frontpage", for example, it is possible to set the *Default front page* to "frontpage".

The module should then implement `hook_menu()` and a page handler, similarly to the following code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['frontpage'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_view',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}

/**
 * Menu callback; shows the frontpage node.
 */
function mymodule_view() {
  $langcode = $GLOBALS['language']->language;

  if ($langcode == "en") {
    drupal_goto('en/home');
  }
  elseif ($langcode == "fr") {
    drupal_goto('fr/accueil');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not set the value of *Default front page* (the `site_frontpage` variable) in *Administration » Configuration » System » Site information* to node/[NID]? If you want different node for the different languages, keep `site_frontpage`in `i18n_variables` in settings.php and visit the *Site Information* page in each language.

Comment: I have tried this, but is not working. For you is working in drupal 7 ?

Comment: The problem with Pierre's proposed solution is that different content is served under the same URL. As the frontpage might get cached for anonymous users, you might run into problems: [#339958, Cached pages returned in wrong language when browser language used](http://drupal.org/node/339958). kiamlaluno's proposed solution should work, but should be completed with a "Vary: Accept-Language" header.

Answer (score 1):

googletorp's solution will not work as is.

If you try to use [`drupal_is_front_page()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_is_front_page/7) in a hook_boot you will get errors because the function libraries haven't even been loaded until after the boot.

This is why EK Kosmos is getting a blank screen (why is anybody developing with error messaging turned off?).

A solution is to use [`hook_boot()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_boot/7), as suggested, but to evaluate directly from the url if it is the front page or not.

Comment: actually, you should use hook_init() instead of hook_boot, since the modules and libraries are then loaded.

Comment: but you should avoid loading all the libraries. This will works http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/121347/1761

Answer (score 1):

I created a (sandbox) module to do exactly this, [Front page redirect](http://drupal.org/sandbox/fietserwin/1621130):

> Drupal allows you to define what content to serve on the home page. However, Drupal does not redirect visitors to that page but instead just serves the content of that page on the front page.
>   ...
>   To alleviate these problems, this module really redirects visitors that arrive at the front page to the page that is defined as front page. It does so using a 301 (Moved Permanently) status code.

Comment: I haven't tested the multilingual aspect, but this works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for hook_boot:

```
module_boot() {
  global $language;
  if (drupal_is_front_page() && $language->language == 'XX') {
    drupal_goto('node/[NID]');
  }
}
```

It's early in the process, so should be quicker and use less resources, than doing it in a theme function.

Comment: Just now I have tried this hook, and is not working. I have checked with debugger and is ok but just he doesn't display the page I want, it display the default home page defined in `admin/config/system/site-information`

Comment: @Ek Kosmos: Hook_boot is special, in that Drupal needs to know about it early on, so it caches the list of modules implementing this hook. All you need to do, is to clear the cache.

Comment: Yes, I have cleared the cache, still is not working.

Comment: @EK Kosmos: hook_boot needs to be in a custom module. Have you tried it there? I like @googletorp's method better. He's catching it sooner than template_preprocess_page. Both work but the load will be less with hook_boot.

Comment: Yes, I have created my custom module where I putted this hook. I have cleared the cache, then a blank page appeared, I have looked into the source code, and there are just header and body tags (which are empty).

Comment: This answer will note work. drupal_is_front_page() is not avaible in hook_boot. This answer http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/121347/1761 was tested and should works in most situations.

Answer (score 0):

For a redirection you don't need to render the page therefor you should use hook_boot instead of hook_menu. In hook_boot you don't have access to all the Drupal function so I tried as much of possible stay with native PHP function.

```
/**
 * hook_boot
 */
function modulename_boot() {
  // Check if it's the front page
  // using hook_boot we avoid wasting resources
  // It's to early to use drupal_is_front_page and we should avoid loading unnecessary extra resource
  if ($_GET['q'] == '') {
    // http_negotiate_language() is a better option but require  pecl_http >= 0.1.0
    // Locale::acceptFromHttp() require intl extension
    $langBrowser = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'],0,2);

    // Get the activated languages on your drupal site
    $langAvailable = language_list();

    // set a default in case the language is not avaible
    $lang = 'en';

    if(isset($langAvailable[$langBrowser]) ){
      $lang = $langAvailable[$langBrowser]->prefix;
    }

    $http_response_code = 302;
    header('Location: ' . $lang, TRUE, $http_response_code);

    drupal_exit();
  }
}
```

Comment: Must use `exit()` and not `drupal_exit()` has it is not available in `hook_boot()` like `drupal_is_front_page()` ;-)